# Why doesn't asyncio always use executors?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, coroutine, aiohttp

I have to send a lot of HTTP requests, once all of them have returned, the program can continue. Sounds like a perfect match for `asyncio`. A bit naively, I wrapped my calls to `requests` in an `async` function and gave them to `asyncio`. This doesn't work.

After searching online, I found two solutions:

- use a library like [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is made to work with `asyncio`
- wrap the blocking code in a call to `run_in_executor`

To understand this better, I wrote a small benchmark. The server-side is a flask program that waits 0.1 seconds before answering a request.

```
from flask import Flask
import time

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    time.sleep(0.1) // heavy calculations here :)
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The client is my benchmark

```
import requests
from time import perf_counter, sleep

# this is the baseline, sequential calls to requests.get
start = perf_counter()
for i in range(10):
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")
stop = perf_counter()
print(f"synchronous took {stop-start} seconds") # 1.062 secs

# now the naive asyncio version
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def get_response():
    r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/")

start = perf_counter()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[get_response() for i in range(10)]))
stop = perf_counter()
print(f"asynchronous took {stop-start} seconds") # 1.049 secs

# the fast asyncio version
start = perf_counter()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    *[loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/') for i in range(10)]))
stop = perf_counter()
print(f"asynchronous (executor) took {stop-start} seconds") # 0.122 secs

#finally, aiohttp
import aiohttp

async def get_response(session):
    async with session.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/") as response:
        return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await get_response(session)

start = perf_counter()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[main() for i in range(10)]))
stop = perf_counter()
print(f"aiohttp took {stop-start} seconds") # 0.121 secs
```

So, an intuitive implementation with `asyncio` doesn't deal with blocking io code. But if you use `asyncio` correctly, it is just as fast as the special `aiohttp` framework. The docs for [coroutines and tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) don't really mention this. Only if you read up on the [loop.run_in_executor()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), it says:

> ```
> # File operations (such as logging) can block the
> # event loop: run them in a thread pool.
> ```

I was surprised by this behaviour. The purpose of asyncio is to speed up blocking io calls. Why is an additional wrapper, `run_in_executor`, necessary to do this?

The whole selling point of `aiohttp` seems to be support for `asyncio`. But as far as I can see, the `requests` module works perfectly - as long as you wrap it in an executor. Is there a reason to avoid wrapping something in an executor ?

Comment: The purpose of ayncio is not to speed things up in general, it's to reduce latency. Both of your approaches do that, while the executor might require a few more resources.

Comment: executor is based on threads. `asyncio` using non-blocking socket so it can request many with one thread but `requests` is not

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But as far as I can see, the requests module works perfectly - as long
>   as you wrap it in an executor. Is there a reason to avoid wrapping
>   something in an executor ?

Running code in executor means to run it in [OS threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)).

`aiohttp` and similar libraries allow to run non-blocking code without OS threads, using coroutines only.

If you don't have much work, difference between OS threads and coroutines is not significant especially comparing to bottleneck - I/O operations. But once you have much work you can notice that OS threads perform relatively worse due to expensively [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

For example, when I change your code to `time.sleep(0.001)` and `range(100)`, my machine shows:

```
asynchronous (executor) took 0.21461606299999997 seconds
aiohttp took 0.12484742700000007 seconds
```

And this difference will only increase according to number of requests.

> The purpose of asyncio is to speed up blocking io calls.

Nope, purpose of `asyncio` is to provide convenient way to control execution flow. `asyncio` allows you to choose how flow works - based on coroutines and OS threads (when you use executor) or on pure coroutines (like `aiohttp` does).

It's `aiohttp`'s purpose to speed up things and it copes with the task as shown above :)

Comment: Asyncio coroutines are not really green threads, because green threads are stackful. Carrying a full stack allows them to switch at arbitrary places and avoid the [function color](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) problem, but at the cost of each green thread being much more heavyweight than a coroutine/[fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)). An example of Python implementation of green threads is the [greenlet](https://pypi.org/project/greenlet/) module and the [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) event loop based on it.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks for clarification! I altered answer.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov, thanks for the elaboration on aiohttps performance, +1 from me :)  I still have some conceptual problems though, currently updating my question

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't understand the intersection between asyncio and aiohttp. Asyncio has non-blocking coroutines without OS-threads ? That sounds like a huge feature. Is this a part of asyncio ? If yes, why isn't that the default. If not, how is aiohttp based on asyncio (async/await are a language feature and not directly a part of asyncio) ?

Comment: hmm, I'm reconsidering this. You have answered my question on executors (OS-threads aren't free). It seems to me that my rephrased question is in fact another question. So I'm making up a new one.

Comment: @lhk Yes, asyncio has non-blocking coroutines without OS-threads, and it _is_ a huge feature. Aiohttp is based on asyncio because it relies on asyncio's abstractions built on top of the raw async/await. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49005651/1600898), particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177895/1600898), for in-depth coverage of the topic.