# Time cost difference between opening a new thread to run requests and aiohttp.ClientSession for async IO?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I understood aiohttp supports the async IO so it's completely single thread. But run_in_executor sort of starts a new thread. But I tested for a task with 1000 downloads, it seems the difference is rather insignificant. But I assume aiohttp should be much faster cause the thread cost. Did I do something wrong?

```
async def get(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            print(url, resp.status)
            print(url, await resp.text())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()     
tasks = [                           
    get("http://www.google.com"),
    get("http://www.google.com")
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))    
loop.close() 




async def get_via_thread(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        response = await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.get, url=url))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I tested for a task with 1000 downloads, it seems the difference
>   is rather insignificant.

Problem probably somewhere in your benchmark. It's hard to say where exactly since you didn't provide one to reproduce :)

As example, you can take a look at [one recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53260688/1113207) where OP tried to compare threads and coroutines and got no difference and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53261628/1113207) where this result explained and fix provided.

Comment: wow thank you. I actually did not see that question, but that answer answered quite well. It seems my assumption is right just my test has to be improved somehow.