# SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, darksky

Hello I am new to python and am trying to work with a Dark Sky python API made by Detrous. When I run the demo code I am presented with an error:

```
forecast = await darksky.get_forecast(
              ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

this error results from:

```
forecast = await darksky.get_forecast(
    latitude, longitude,
    extend=False, # default `False`
    lang=languages.ENGLISH, # default `ENGLISH`
    units=units.AUTO, # default `auto`
    exclude=[weather.MINUTELY, weather.ALERTS] # default `[]`
)
```

I am not too sure how to resolve this issue and am using python 3.

Thanks

Comment: await should always be inside an async function

Comment: Can you try by removing `await` before `darksky.get_forecast(`

Comment: try putting the whole code you presented here inside a function `async def main()` then call it

Answer (score 18):

I think this answer will be useful for people who search the same question as me.
To use async functions in synchronous context you can use event loop. You can write it from scratch for education purposes.
You can start from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116910/14154287
And continue education with David Beazley books.

But developers of asyncio already did this for you.

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
forecast = loop.run_until_complete(darksky.get_forecast(...<here place arguments>...))
loop.close()
```

Comment: If you use Python 3,7 or later, this can be simplified to `asyncio.run(darksky.get_forecast(...))`

Answer (score 2):

The `await` keyword can be used only in asynchronous functions and methods. You can read more on asynchronous code to understand why.

The solution, without having any details about what you want to accomplish and how, is to use `darksky = DarkSky(API_KEY)` instead of `darksky = DarkSkyAsync(API_KEY)`.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of python (v3.7+), you can call async functions in sync contexts by using `asyncio.run`:

```
import asyncio

forecast = asyncio.run(darksky.get_forecast(...))
```