# Run two asynco loop in a python script (telethon, aiopg)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon, aiopg

I would like to use Telethon (Telegram bot) and aiopg (PostgreSQL) library.

Telethon example:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    # Getting information about yourself
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(me.stringify())

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('hi!')

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

aiopg example:

```
import aiopg

dsn = 'dbname=aiopg user=aiopg password=passwd host=127.0.0.1'


async def notify(conn):
    async with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for i in range(5):
            msg = "message {}".format(i)
            print('Send ->', msg)
            await cur.execute("NOTIFY channel, %s", (msg,))

        await cur.execute("NOTIFY channel, 'finish'")


async def listen(conn):
    async with conn.cursor() as cur:
        await cur.execute("LISTEN channel")
        while True:
            msg = await conn.notifies.get()
            if msg.payload == 'finish':
                return
            else:
                print('Receive <-', msg.payload)


async def main():
    async with aiopg.create_pool(dsn) as pool:
        async with pool.acquire() as conn1:
            listener = listen(conn1)
            async with pool.acquire() as conn2:
                notifier = notify(conn2)
                await asyncio.gather(listener, notifier)
    print("ALL DONE")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I would like to use both in a same python script.
I tried to find the solution and it is maybe the asyncio.gather(...), but I don't know how can I combine these two library, how to start both loop.
Can you please help me?

Comment: I think you're looking for `asyncio.create_task()`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528272/what-does-asyncio-create-task-do) you can find more details on how it works.

Comment: @TheKill-996 Thanks, yes. I found examples like these:
loop.create_task(client.get_messages('telegram', 10))
loop.create_task(client.send_message('me', 'Using asyncio!'))
loop.create_task(client.download_profile_photo('telegram'))

But these are only "commands", I don't know, how can I receive events like that:
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.reply('hi!')

I'm sorry, I don't fully understand that whole async thing.

Comment: Decorators like `client.on(events.NewMessage)` are just a convenient way to invoke [`add_event_handler`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.updates.UpdateMethods.add_event_handler). You can calways call it directly in your setup code.

Comment: Note that `client.start()` and `client.run_until_disconnected()` can both be `await`-ed if you're inside an `async def`. You're already using `asyncio.gather`, so you could also have the client setup in some `asyncio def` and gather all the code together. Asyncio docs are worth a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new async function which creates a new client instance and add all the handlers you need, for the sake of this example I showed some example handlers of mine.

```
async def init_bot() -> TelegramClient:
    client = TelegramClient(
                 session="trade-bot",
                 api_hash=Config.API_HASH,
                 api_id=Config.API_ID,
             )
    await client.start(bot_token=Config.BOT_TOKEN)

    client.add_event_handler(
        register_handler,
        events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r"^[\/?!]register$"),
    )
    client.add_event_handler(
        get_webhook_handler,
        events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r"^[\/?!]webhook$"),
    )
    client.add_event_handler(
        status_handler,
        events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r"^[\/?!]status$"),
    )
    _LOG.info("Bot client started")
    return client
```

then later on you main function

```
client = await init_bot()
await client.connect()
# the below code is non-blocking
asyncio.create_task(client.run_until_disconnected())
```