# Python asyncio: how are tasks scheduled?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm new to Python asyncio and I'm doing some experiments. I have the following code:

```
async def say_after(n, s):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    print(s)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'a'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'b'))
    await task1
    print('x', flush=True)
    await task2
    print('y', flush=True)

asyncio.run(main())
```

And the output:

```
b
a
x
y
```

I don't understand the order here. Can someone help explain? Especially why x comes after b and a?

Comment: If you try the code it actually only prints `x` and `y`. If you await the tasks, the output is the following: `x y b a`

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Hi sorry I copied a wrong version of the code... I have updated the code and it should produce the same output as in the question.

Comment: Already burned my closure vote prior to the edit (thanks, much clearer now!), but I think [What does asyncio.create_task() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528272/what-does-asyncio-create-task-do) is the proper answer. You're spawning new tasks; simply omit this call if you want to keep everything sequential in a single task.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks! This one really helped me to understand what is a task.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `say_after` (without `await`) creates a coroutine object, but *does not start it yet*.

If you `await` on the coroutine object, *then* you are executing the coroutine until the Python encounters one of `await` or `return` (or end of function) in the coroutine. "Executing" here means transforming the coroutine into a `Task` object and put that object in the async loop.

However, `create_task` immediately 'starts' the coroutine and put them tasks in the async loop (though, because this is async instead of parallel, execution does not actually begin until Python encounters `await` in `main()`).

In your situation, as soon as Python sees the `await task1`, it 'leaves' main() and loops among `task1` and `task2` back and forth (because both tasks have been put in the async loop by create_task) until `task1` is completed (because task1 is the one being await-ed on). Because task2 had scheduled itself to wait for a shorter time, it finishes first. About 1 second later, task1 completes, and only then execution returns to main() (because, remember, it was task1 that main() had been await-ing on).

At this point, *both* task1 and task2 has completed; the `await task2` line practically does nothing; it's just "wrapping up" task2 and (almost) immediately returns.

Answer (score 0):

> Especially why x comes after b and a?

`b` is printed in `task2` about 1 second after the start of `main`, and `a` is printed in `task1` about 2 seconds after the start of `main`. The `await task1` waits for `task1`, and so waits about 2 seconds. So by the time `await task1` completes, both `b` and `a` would have been printed.

(The "about"s in the above are deliberate... there would be variations, but in most situations, they would be small)

Answer (score 0):

`await task1` basically says that do not execute the next lines of code until `task1` is finished (i.e. the execution of `say_after(2, 'a')`).

`task1` takes longer than `task2` to execute, so by the time you "awaited" `task1`, `task2` is already finished executing. So putting `await task2` below `await task1` is somewhat useless here. If you swap these two lines, the output will be different.

That's why `'b'` is printed before `'a'`. And not until `'a'` is printed, `'x'` and `'y'` could be printed.