# Asynchronous Web Scraping, Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

Im trying to run this function every 2seconds forever :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio

async def scrape():
    test = []
    r = requests.get(coin_desk)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features='xml') 
    title = soup.find_all('title')[2]
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    for x in title:
        test.append(x)
        print(test)
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
try:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(scrape())
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```

If i use

```
run_forever()
```

instead of

```
run_until_complete(scrape())
```

nothing gets printed out, it just runs forever and skips the function it seems.

Comment: Do you get any error messages with an exception / stack trace?  Have you tried adding other prints to see which lines you actually reach before it exits?

Comment: No error messages, when i try to use run_forever() nothing gets printed out. It just runs forever and skips the function completly.

Comment: the async routine (`scrape`) was never placed into the runtime/evloop. `run_until_complete` includes the parameter to queue a routine for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The async routine (`scrape`) was never placed into the event loop.

You can add it with

```py
loop.create_task(routine)
```

See:
[What does asyncio.create_task() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528272/what-does-asyncio-create-task-do#62529343)