# Asyncio or Concurrent in python

Tags: python, loops, concurrency, async-await, python-asyncio

I want do **two functions at same time** That the end is related to each other For example :

```
def func1 ():
    while True:
        print('it fine')
```

That this is only for beauty and does not do anything special.

But the next function plays the main role of the program and I want func1 to run until it is finished.

```
def func2():
    number=1000
    for i in range(number):
        if i % 541 ==0:
            print('Horay !!!')
            return
```

Well, here are two questions, one is how can I do this and two can I get out of func1?

i need output like this :

```
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
Horay !!!
```

But I want exactly use two Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten your sample using asyncio. Pay attention to several points:

- Using `async def` declarations
- Concurrent coroutines are started by `create_task()`
- Coroutines should use at least one `await` invocation within to allow concurrent coroutines to be executed cooperatively. (Pay attention to `await asyncio.sleep()`)

For deeper understanding refer you to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work) and [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

```
import asyncio


async def func1():
    while True:
        print('it fine')
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def func2():
    number = 1000
    task = asyncio.create_task(func1())  # run concurrent task
    for i in range(1, number):
        if i % 541 == 0:
            print('Horay !!!')
            task.cancel()  # stop task
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

asyncio.run(func2())  # run program entrypoint coroutine
```

```
...
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
it fine
Horay !!!
```

Comment: woow its work correct,But I can not fully understand it, can you please tell me where you learned in addition suggest a good source.