# Python's asyncio.gather() doesn't seem to be running tasks asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, yfinance

I need to run 20 tasks asynchronously (each task runs the same function, but with a different argument). Each task uses Python's `yfinance` API module. This is my current method:

1. Define a list `args` with 20 elements; each element is the argument to be passed to the corresponding task.
2. Define an async function `get_data` which I will run 20 times with a different argument each time.
3. Define an async function `main` which will use `asyncio.gather` to run the 20 tasks asynchronously.

And here is the (pseudo)code:

```
import asyncio

stocks = []
args = ['arg1', 'arg2', ... , 'arg20']


async def get_data(arg):
    stock = Stock(arg)
    # do some yfinance calls
    return stock


async def main():
    global stocks
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(arg)) for arg in args]
    stocks = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


asyncio.run(main())

print(stocks)  # should be a list of 20 return values from the 20 tasks
```

Assume each task on its own takes 4 seconds to run. Then the 20 tasks should run in 4 seconds if it's running asynchronously. However, it is running in 80 seconds. If I remove all the async code and just run it synchronously, it runs in the same amount of time. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `get_data()` function is not awaiting anything, which is a red flag that it's async in name only, but in fact is blocking. To get benefits of asyncio, you need to use an async library for accessing stocks (or whatever else the code needs), and use `await`.

Comment: You might want to read up on what "asynchronous" actually means – it is *not* the same as "in parallel". [How does asyncio actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work) could be a worthwhile read, albeit a long one.

Comment: @S.Naj any feedback?

Comment: As a newbie to asynchronous code, I did not realize there was a difference between asynchronous and "in parallel." @ArtiomKozyrev 's solution works exactly as desired, so I guess I learned that the ThreadPoolExecutor module runs synchronous code "in parallel," which is not the same as running code asynchronously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have checked documentation of `yfinance` and see `requests` library in requirements, the library ins not async. It means that you should not use it with asyncio module, you should use `theading.Thread` or `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead.

I made the following example for you, please run it and share your results.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import yfinance as yf
from pprint import pprint
from time import monotonic


def get_stocks_data(name: str) -> dict:
    """some random function which extract some data"""
    tick = yf.Ticker(name)
    tick_info = tick.info
    return tick_info


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # some random stocks
    stocks = [
        'AAPL', 'AMD', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'TSLA', 'MSFT',
        'AAPL', 'AMD', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'TSLA', 'MSFT',
    ]
    start_time = monotonic()
    # you can choose max_workers number higher and check if app works faster
    # e.g choose 16 as max number of workers
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(get_stocks_data, stocks)

    for r in results:
        pprint(r)

    print("*" * 150)
    print(monotonic() - start_time)
```

Comment: This solution worked exactly as desired. For 10 tasks running synchronously, run time was about 60 seconds. With this solution, run time was about 7 seconds, as expected. Thanks a lot for your effort and commitment.