# Python Asyncio & Websocket how to avoid global variable?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a python socket server using asyncio and websockets. When the websocket is active 100+ devices will connect and hold their connection waiting for commands/messages.

There are two threads the first thread accepts connections and adds their details to a global variable then waits for messages from the device:

```
async def thread1(websocket, path):
    client_address = await websocket.recv()
    CONNECTIONS[client_address] = websocket
    async for message in websocket:
        ... do something with message

start_server = websockets.serve(thread1, host, port)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.ensure_future(thread2())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The second thread processes some user data and once it needs to send a command it accesses a global variable to get the websocket info:

```
thread2()
    ...some data processing 
    soc = CONNECTIONS[ipaddress] 
    await soc.send("some message")
```

My question: What's the best way to allow another thread to send messages?

I can keep the global variable `safe` using thread locking and a function made only to process that data, however global variables aren't ideal. I cannot send information between threads since thread1 is `stuck` waiting to receive messages.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I would like to say is the incorrect use of the term *thread*. You use `asyncio` and here the concept is used - *coroutine* (coroutine is wrapped into a asyncio task). How it differs from threads can be found, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work).

The `websockets` server spawns a new task for each incoming connection (there are the same number of connections and spawned tasks). I don't see anything wrong with the global object, at least in a small script. However, below I gave an example where I placed this in a separate class.

Also, in this case, special synchronization between coroutines is not required, since they are implemented through *cooperative multitasking* (in fact, all are executed in one thread, transferring control at certain points.)

Here is a simple example in which the server stores a dictionary of incoming connections and starts a task that every 2 seconds, notifies all clients and sends them the current time. The server also prints confirmation from clients to the console.

```
# ws_server.py
import asyncio
import websockets
import datetime


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.connections = {}
        self.is_active = False
        self.server = None

    async def start(self):
        self.is_active = True
        self.server = await websockets.serve(self.handler, self.host, self.port)
        asyncio.create_task(self.periodic_notifier())

    async def stop(self):
        self.is_active = False
        self.server.close()
        await self.wait_closed()

    async def wait_closed(self):
        await self.server.wait_closed()

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        self.connections[websocket.remote_address] = websocket
        try:
            async for message in websocket:
                print(message)
        except ConnectionClosedError as e:
            pass
        del self.connections[websocket.remote_address]
        print(f"Connection {websocket.remote_address} is closed")

    async def periodic_notifier(self):
        while self.is_active:
            await asyncio.gather(
                *[ws.send(f"Hello time {datetime.datetime.now()}") for ws in self.connections.values()],
                return_exceptions=True)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)


async def main():
    server = Server("localhost", 8080)
    await server.start()
    await server.wait_closed()

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
# ws_client.py
import asyncio
import websockets


async def client():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8080"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        async for message in websocket:
            print(message)
            await websocket.send(f"ACK {message}")


asyncio.run(client())
```