# asyncio running from a synchronous (standard) function

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Having read the documents and watched a number of videos, i am testing `asyncio` as an alternative to `threading`.

The docs are here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

I have constructed the following code with the expectation that it would produce the following.

```
before the sleep
hello
world
```

But in fact is produces this (`world` comes before `hello`):

```
before the sleep
world
hello
```

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import time


def main():
    ''' main entry point for the program '''
    # create the event loop and add to the loop
    # or run directly.

    asyncio.run(main_async())
    return

async def main_async():
    ''' the main async function '''
    await foo()
    await bar()
    return

async def foo():
    print('before the sleep')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    # time.sleep(0)
    print('world')
    return

async def bar():
    print('hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return



if __name__=='__main__':
    ''' This is executed when run from the command line '''
    main()
```

The `main()` function calls the async `main_async()` function which in turn calls both the `foo` and `bar` async functions and both of those run the `await asyncio.sleep(x)` command.

So my question is: why is the `hello` `world` comming in the wrong (unexpected) order given that i was expecting `world` to be printed *approximately 2 seconds after* `hello` ?

Comment: I highly recommend you read [This answer][1], it explains how asyncio works and it might give you a good overview on the subject


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work

Comment: This is very interesting (with regards to generators in previous versions of python) and i have read & watched similar. But am still left unaware of what i have done wrong or misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `await`ed `foo()` immediately, so `bar()` was never scheduled until `foo()` had run to completion; the execution of `main_async` will never do things *after* an `await` until the `await` has completed. If you want to schedule them both and let them interleave, replace:

```
await foo()
await bar()
```

with something like:

```
await asyncio.gather(foo(), bar())
```

which will convert both awaitables to tasks, scheduling both on the running asyncio event loop, then wait for both tasks to run to completion. With both scheduled at once, when one blocks on an `await` (and *only* `await`-based blocks, because only `await` yields control back to the event loop), the other will be allowed to run (and control can only return to the other task when the now running task `await`s or finishes).

Basically, you have to remember that `asyncio` is *cooperative* multitasking. If you're only executing one task, and that task performs an `await`, there is nothing else to schedule, so nothing else runs until that `await` completes. If you block by any means other than an `await`, you still hold the event loop, and nothing else will get a chance to run, even if it's ready to go. So to gain any benefit from `asyncio` you need to be careful to:

1. Ensure other tasks are launched in time to occupy the event loop while the original task(s) are blocking on `await`.
2. Ensure you only block via `await`, so you don't monopolize the event loop unnecessarily.

Comment: So are you saying that the error was that the code failed to use the `gather()` function and that two consecutive `awaits` are insufficient (synchronous) ?

Comment: I do confirm that *this correction has worked* and am waiting to see if there are other comments otherwise will mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: @D.L: Yeah, that's basically it. In this case, it's really no different than threading; your original code is similar to running `t = threading.Thread(target=foo); t.start(); t.join()` first, then following up with `t = threading.Thread(target=bar); t.start(); t.join()`, so the `foo` thread is launched and waited for before launching the `bar` thread at all. `asyncio.gather` makes it behave more like `t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo); t1.start(); t2 = threading.Thread(target=bar); t2.start(); t1.join(); t2.join()`, starting both threads before it tries to wait for either so they can both run.

Comment: May i ask, given the explanation above is there a preference for one over the other with respect to `threading` or `asyncio` (for example an efficiency gain) ?

Comment: @D.L: Nothing meaningful, at least on CPython. On GIL-free Python interpreters (there aren't many, and they're typically well behind the state of the art), `threading` can provide a major performance boost for CPU bound work (and even on CPython, if it's heavy number crunching with third party packages like `numpy` that release the GIL internally, threading can boost CPU performance). But otherwise, it's pretty similar, and the overhead for `asyncio` is, at least in theory, lower. `asyncio` also makes synchronization easier (if you don't `await`, you're guaranteed not to race).

Comment: The downside to `asyncio` being that you have to be more disciplined about explicitly handing control back to the event loop, where `threading`, being preemptive multitasking, hands off between threads automatically. Of course, that makes synchronization more critical/necessary in threaded programs, and opens you to all sorts of race conditions `asyncio` can't have (or can easily avoid).