# python 3.8 Future is returned instead of value when awaited

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7, python-3.8

I am having an issue with python 3.8.5 vs 3.7

given method:

```
import asyncio
import functools

_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()


async def request_async(*args, **kwargs) -> requests.Response:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    response = await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, functools.partial(requests.request, *args, **kwargs))
    return response
```

and a call:

```
 response = await request_async(protocol, url, headers=headers, *args, **kwargs)
```

^^ works in python 3.7 and returns a **Response** as per signature
although in python 3.8 returns a **Future** in order to get to work needs to be awaited second time.

```
 response = await (await request_async(protocol, url, headers=headers, *args, **kwargs))
```

I would appreciate some insights where to look and why it would happen.

Comment: Hi there, I am attempting to reproduce your issue, but I'm having a little bit of trouble, as the example code you have given does not execute.  It needs `from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor` I presume, but your `request_async` also references `requests` and I've been unable to figure out what that's supposed to be.  Can you edit your code to correct it?

Comment: +1 To @OmnipotentEntity - eg.: arent you using aiohttp request which is awaitable? BTW. Why are you not using aiohttp request directly?

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the same output in both python 3.8.5 and python 3.7.8:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor 

_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

async def request_async(*args, **kwargs) -> requests.Response:
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  response = await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, functools.partial(requests.request, *args, **kwargs))
  return response

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
req_result = loop.run_until_complete(request_async('GET', "http://example.com/"))
loop.close()

print(req_result)
```

Note that the variable `req_result` is using a `get_event_loop` to perform the evaluation of the async function in a non-async environment.  See this Stack Overflow answer for more details about why this is required: [How does asyncio actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work/51116910#51116910)

Unfortunately, as structured, your question does not provide enough information to answer your specific point on what the difference is between the two versions and why it would occur.  It may simply be a difference in when lazy expressions (such as an async function) are evaluated in other async contexts (perhaps viewing the data from the repl or in a debugger).  But this is simply an off the cuff guess.  But due to how you're calling the async function in your question, I figured this answer would be more valuable to you, as it answers your your implicit question ("How do I get this to work?") rather than your explicit one ("Why does this difference exist between versions?").