# What is the point of having to put await in front of each async function in Python?

Tags: python, async-await

In Python, we need an `await` keyword before each coroutine object to have it called by the event loop. But when we put `await`, it makes the call blocking. It follows that we end up doing the same thing as we do in the blocking fashion. What is the point of having such a use?

https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/

https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does asyncio actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work)

Comment: "But when we put ``await``, it makes the call blocking." What makes you think that? The first links says for example "Coroutines run synchronously until they hit an await and **then they pause, give up control to the event loop, and something else can happen.**"

Comment: The following lines after the line in which `await` is called have to wait for the promise to resolve. So it is blocking its scope, am I wrong? So unlike JS, which we don't have to put await, we need to block the scope for each async function. This reduces the same thing. I'm so confused.

Comment: The point of ``await`` is that *other* coroutines ("scopes") can run while the current one is suspended ("blocks").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does asyncio actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` makes the call *locally* blocking, but the "wait" is transmitted through the async function (which is itself awaited), such that when it reaches the *reactor* the entire task can be moved to a waitlist and an other can be run instead.

Furthermore you do not *need* an `await`, you could also `spawn` the coroutine (to a separate task, which you may or may not wait on), or use one of the "future combinators" (`asyncio.gather`, `asyncio.wait`, ...) to run it concurrently with others.

Answer (score 9):

Using `await` does NOT make the call synchronous. It is just syntactic sugar to make it look like "normal" sequential code. But while the result of the function call is `await`ed the event loop still continues in the background.

For example the following code executes `foo()` twice which will `await` a `sleep`. But even though it uses `await` the second function invokation will execute before the first one finishes. Ie. it runs in parallel.

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('started')
    await asyncio.gather(
        foo(),
        foo(),
    )

async def foo():
    print('starting foo')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('foo finished.')

asyncio.run(main())
```

prints:

```
started
starting foo
starting foo
foo finished.
foo finished.
```

Comment: "parallel" is misleading. you mean concurrent

Comment: I think the author of the question asked about the coroutine being blocked. Yes. The await call blocks. It does not block the entire thread of python. But it definitely blocks the particular coroutine in which await is called. If there is another coroutine then the event loop can execute this one. I think what people expect is that python would make an asynchronous call and when this call is done a callback function is called. We do not have callbacks here.