# How to use python async?

Tags: python

Recently I learnt about the asynchronous by using python
and I try it in my code (for inserting data into database) but it doesn't work as I expect

```py
async def task1():
  #insert something to database
  #it more or less took 15 - 20 sec for finish this function
  print('Task 1 finished')

async def task2():
  #insert something to database
  #it more or less took 25 - 30 sec for finish
  print('Task 2 finished')

async def task3():
  #insert something to database
  #it more or less took 300 - 400 sec for finish
  print('Task 3 finished')
```

And my function do something like that and I call it in the main like this

```py
async def main():
  print('Script start...')
  task1 = asyncio.create_task(task1())
  task3 = asyncio.create_task(task3())
  task2 = asyncio.create_task(task2())
```

but the result not like I expect

```
#result from that code
Task 1 finished
Task 3 finished
Task 2 finished

#result what I expect
Task 1 finished
Task 2 finished
Task 3 finished
```

So can someone explain more about this to me. Thank you

Comment: If the time consuming operations in the tasks are synchronous then the first started task has to finish before the next can even be started.

Comment: I see thank you for the insight now I know why the result not what I expect

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work

Comment: Why do you expect the result 1, 2, 3 when you run the tasks In the order 1, 3, 2?