# Is asyncio affected by the GIL?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, gil

On [this](https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-vs-threading/) page I read this:

> Coroutines in the asyncio module are not limited by the Global Interpreter Lock or GIL.

But how is this possible if both the `asyncio` event loop and the `threading` threads are running in a single Python process with GIL?

As far as I understand, the impact of the GIL on `asyncio` will not be as strong as on `threading`, because in the case of `threading`, the interpreter will switch to useless operations, such as `time.sleep()`.  Therefore, when working with `asyncio`, it is recommended to use `asyncio.sleep()`.

I understand that these tools are designed for slightly different things, `threading` is more often used to execute "legacy" blocking code for IO-Bound operations, and `asyncio` for non-blocking code.

Comment: I call bull on the way this is presented. I'm going to consult an expert in this stuff separately, but I think the wording is totally disingenuous, if not just flatly false.

Comment: The GIL is there to protect Python's state when you're doing threading. When using asyncio, this form of concurrency is not doing threading, so locking is not needed and the GIL doesn't really come into the picture. If you're mixing threading AND asyncio, then the GIL will be there as usual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are really *two* kinds of answers to this, depending on whether you take the GIL as the concrete implementation or the conceptual limitation. The answer is **No**'ish for the former, and **Yes**'ish for the latter.

---

**No**, `asyncio` concurrency is not bound to the GIL.

The GIL exists to synchronise *thread* concurrency: When more than one thread is active at once, only the thread that owns the GIL may execute Python code. This means that if another thread needs to run, ownership of the GIL must pass from the current executing thread to the other thread. This is realised via *preemptive* concurrency, meaning the currently executing thread is forcefully paused regularly.
As such, the GIL is the mechanism handling the switching of control between the currently executing thread and all other threads. This is a very wasteful mechanism that becomes worse the more threads there are.

In contrast, `asyncio` has its own concurrency synchronisation: `async`/`await` provides *cooperative* concurrency by design. That means the currently executing task can *voluntarily yield* control to any other waiting task. This allows the `asyncio` event loop to freely schedule tasks.
As such, the GIL is not involved in switching control between the currently executing task and all other tasks. An `async` framewok such as `asyncio` can achieve very efficient task switching, regardless of the number of tasks.

---

**Yes**, `asyncio` is bound by the GIL.

While `asyncio` can efficiently switch tasks, it cannot run more than one task at any moment. As such, it does not actually avoid the conceptual limitation of the GIL: running more than one operation at once. While `asyncio` applications avoid the *inefficiency* of the GIL for many operations, it does not avoid the *limitation* of the GIL for parallel operations.
Notably, solving this limitation would require solving the exact same challenge as for removing the GIL: providing a safe synchronisation when executing Python code in parallel.

In addition, `asyncio` still cannot execute *blocking* code concurrently as tasks but must fallback to threading for these. Thus, `asyncio`'s backend for executing blocking code concurrently is directly bound by the GIL.

Comment: "That means the currently executing task can voluntarily yield control to any other waiting task." How, if not via the GIL?

Comment: @roganjosh Via [the power of async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005651/how-does-asyncio-actually-work). The TLDR is that an `asyncio` Task can yield the same way a generator can `yield`. You could see `zip` over multiple generators as a (very) primitive event loop, for example.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question

> Is `asyncio` affected by the GIL?

depends on what **exactly** you mean by *"affected"*.

The Python Docs define the [GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) as the

> mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that only one thread executes Python bytecode at a time.

Since the `asyncio` event loop **always** runs in a single thread, I would argue the topic of the GIL is simply **irrelevant** most of the time, when you are using `asyncio`.

But of course you *can* still employ additional threads, when you work with `asyncio`. (A popular example is the [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) used with [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).)

And in that case, the limitations of the GIL **of course apply**.

To be fair to the article you cited, a few sentences later the author qualifies his statement:

> The concept of a GIL does not make sense in the context of coroutines as all coroutines in an event loop execute within a single thread.

I would be charitable and interpret this as saying essentially "the GIL does not matter in the context of coroutines". And that is fair enough, keeping in mind the caveat I mentioned above.